# starting mongodb from a bash shell script

Tags: mac, shell, script

I am trying to start a `mongodb` using a cronjob+shell-script combo.

In the shell, mongoDB starts when I enter `$ mongod`, however my executable shell script fails with `mongod: command not found`.  I then tried `./mongodb`, and the error was `No such file or directory`.

It seems like it might be some sort of path problem (FWIW I have installed mongoDB using homebrew) but I'm not sure where to look to fix it.

How might I start a mongoDB from a shell script?

Comment: Do you know the full directory path to the mongod binary? If the answer is no, the following command should work: "sudo find / -name mongod"

Comment: +1. yes, which mongod returns a full path -- and substituting that in my script fixes the problem. make it a full answer and i'll accept it. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine the full directory path to the mongod binary by running the following command:

"sudo find / -name mongod"

Substitute the full path and filename of the binary instead of making a relative call to the binary as you were in the past in your script and you should see the results you're looking for.